# From File path to HttpPostedFileBase in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, httppostedfilebase

In My project i have file upload control. After save the file path i need to get file path and create `HttpPostedFileBase` object and assign in model. So I tried like this .

**View**

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top:1%;">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.file_regn_no_upload, 
      new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm",@type="file" })
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
FileStream xfileStream = new FileStream(xvehicle_code.regn_no_upload, FileMode.Open);
string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(xvehicle_code.regn_no_upload);
fileImage = new Class.MemoryFile(xfileStream, mimeType, Path.GetFileName(xvehicle_code.regn_no_upload));
xvehicle_code.file_regn_no_upload = fileImage;
```

**Model**

```
public HttpPostedFileBase file_regn_no_upload { get; set; }
```

How can i show the file upload with values.
am using **MVC5** 
**VS2017**

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. You cannot set the value of a file input in code. The only way if can be set if by the user selecting a file in the browser

Comment: unable to set the value. am tried code some error happening that also am showing

Comment: Did you read the first comment - you **cannot** set the value of a file input in code (for security reasons)

Comment: yes i tried not showing. and what i am tried that also showing error

Comment: I'm voting to close because no progress could be made to understand the question through comments. No additional information was provided by the OP on request.

Comment: @StephenMuecke filepath to HttpPostedFileBase not working